# How to check if viewport is smaller than a certain width using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I want to have a simple statement to set a variable bool to false or true. isMobile should be set to true when the viewport is smaller then 768px and above this amount it should be set to false.

I don't know why the following code does nothing. Also there is no error in the console log.

```
var w = $(window).width();
var isMobile = false;

function resizer() {
    if (w < 768) {
        console.log("resize");
        isMobile = true;
    } else {
        isMobile = false;
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizer();
});
```

Comment: While I don't know what happens when `isMobile `is toggled, you can probably achieve what you're ultimately trying to do with a simple media query without having to use JavaScript and/or jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you don't measure the width on every resize. Try this way:

```
var isMobile = false;

function resizer() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    if (w < 768) {
        console.log("resize");
        isMobile = true;
    } else { 
        isMobile = false;
    }
}

$(window).on('load resize', function(){ 
    resizer();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Move `var w = $(window).width();` inside `resizer()`. This will get the value of *current* dimensions of `window`.

See the comments inline in the code.

```
var isMobile = false;

function resizer() {
    var w = $(window).width();
    // Move this inside resize handler

    if (w < 768) {
        console.log("resize");
        isMobile = true;
    } else {
        isMobile = false;
    }
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resizer();
}).trigger('resize');
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// 
// Trigger event on page load
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use these ways:

- Method 1: Check if the user is on a mobile device

> const isMobile = /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

- Method 2: Check if the screen width is less than 680 pixels

> const isMobileWidth = window.innerWidth < 680;